# TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null while using textContent

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
let firstCard = 10;
let secondCard = 4;
let sum = firstCard + secondCard;
let hasBlackJack = false;
let isAlive = true;
let message = ""
let messageEl = document.getElementById("message-el");
let sumEl = document.querySelector("#sum-el");
let cardsEl = document.getElementById("cards-el");
messageEl.textContent = "Do you want to draw a new card?";

function startGame() {
    cardsEl.textContent = "Cards : " + firstCard + " " + secondCard;
    sumEl.textContent = "Sum :" + sum;
    if (sum <= 20) {
        message = "Do you want to draw a new card?";
    } else if (sum === 21) {
        message = "You have got blackjack!";
        hasBlackJack = ture;
    } else {
        message = "You are out of the game!";
        isAlive = false;
    }
    messageEl.textContent = message;
}
```

Comment: We need to see your HTML. It seems that your `messageEl` is null.

Comment: `hasBlackJack = ture;`  <-- typo.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
let messageEl = document.getElementById("message-el");
```

is not returning an element.

It is because at the point when the code executes, that element doesn't exist in the DOM. This could be because you don't have any element with that ID or because you need to move the code to execute after that element is parsed into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Marcus's answer is right, either the element id is miswritten or you are trying to access it before it was rendered. You can try one of those things below (If option 1 does not solve your problem, move on to option 2. If option 2 also fails, continue with option 3, and so on.

1. Check if the element ID "message-el" from the HTML tag is spelled correctly.
2. Check if you can move the script to execute below the HTML tag that contains id="message-el", preferably right before the < body > closing tag.
3. Try to wrap your script inside a startUpFunction and execute it after DOM is completely loaded:

   ```
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      startUpFunction()
      //do some stuff
    });
   ```
4. In cases where the rendering of elements via Ajax occurs after the DOM is completely loaded, you can try the following trick: write a function that checks if the element is present, if not you wait a few seconds and call the function again recursively:

   ```
    let messageEl //Declare global

    const delay = ms => new Promise(res => (setTimeout(res, ms)));

    async function waitForMessageElLoad() {
        messageEl = document.getElementById("message-el");
        if (!messageEl) { //Not found - wait 500ms and try again.
            await delay(500);
            waitForMessageElLoad();
            return
        }
    }
   ```

Hope it helps.
Cheers!

Comment: Just to be clear, you can't have anything below the `<html>` element. And while setting up a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler certainly will work, placing your `<script>` element just before the closing `body` tag is a little bit better because by the time the HTML parser reaches that point, all the HTML of the `body` will be loaded and ready for access AND you've avoided setting aside any memory to store the event handler as well as processing the event.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about the HTML tag that contains id="message-el". I edited it to make the text easier to understand. Thanks